# Object oriented programming - subobject vs globals (use case)

Tags: object-oriented, object-oriented-design, object

I am developing a nethack-like game, and I would like an advice  how to approach the design part. For now I got class like Location, Npc, Item etc. But I've got a problem how to easily access parts of location.

Lets say I have an object Door inside (not inherited). If player is inside location it is easy to check whether door are opened. But on the other hand (I got this solution with my previous non-object implementation) I had a script that at 0600 opened all shops. But now I need to iterate thru all locations, check whether are doors inside, and open them if location is a shop. Is it really optimized way to do it?

I could also do a globals (like singleton) with door states and quickly run through those - but it would be hardly an OOP.

What are the possibilities here?

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to do this in an object-oriented way is to put a reference to each of the shops in a Shop Collection, so that you only have to iterate through those specifically.

```
var shops = new list<Location>();

// When you add a location
if (location.Type = LocationTypes.Shop)
    shops.Add(location);

// Open the shop doors
foreach(var shop in shops)
    shop.OpenDoors();
```

But you should time your code first to see if you even need this optimization.  You might find out that iterating through all locations is already fast enough.

Comment: I was thinking about it, but it seems that for each feature as such I need additional list. But you are right I can do some measurements, maybe poverthinking is futile. Still - i like optimizing algorhytm in advance :)

Comment: Don't worry too much about memory. You are just storing a reference to the object, not a copy of the object itself. Unless you have millions of shops it would not take up much memory, just a memory address for each shop object.